# How to profile and measure C#/C++/Java code performance with VSCode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, performance-testing, memory-profiling

I have searched somewhat within VSCode extensions, plugins, googled, but nothing seems to give me similar tool as standard VS provides.

[There is a whole list of code profilers](https://www.codeguru.com/dotnet/performance-analysis-using-the-visual-studio-code-profilers/) for the big VS, (only .NET and managed c++)..

With the 'real' VisualStudio you have [pretty advanced profiling tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2019), supporting many languages, that MSVS supports.

But I can't get anything for VSCode.
(Yap, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/how-can-i-profile-c-code-running-on-linux), but seems to me much too complicated. If there was anything with GUI, similar to JavaScript built- in profiler - would be awesome :)

Is anyone aware of such possibility for C#/C++/Java, please ?

Target: Linux server, Linux embedded, but I can run (just C# code) on windows too.

Comment: For what it's worth, profiling is only available in the expensive editions of plain old VS

Comment: @Flydog57  Oh, so "IT'S A FEATURE" again :D

Comment: For Java there is https://visualvm.github.io/

Comment: Partial answer for linux C++ profiling, but not directly for VSCode:
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/gprof-tutorial/

Comment: For Java there is now available Codewind profiler as extension to VSCode.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.codewind-java-profiler

Comment: you can use Benchmarking with MemoryDiagnoser, in Youtube, there are loads of tutorials on how to use them, https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet